# db.getConnection is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to make a post request to my first app, but every time I go to make the post, it gives me this error: `TypeError: db.getConnection is not a function`

I have tried all of stack overflows suggestions, but I still can't seem to get it to work after messing around with the code for the last 2 days. I am a beginner so please forgive me, but here is what my code looks like...

my db.js looks like this....

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var mainDb = mysql.createPool({
  host     : process.env.mysql_host,
  user     : process.env.mysql_user,
  password : process.env.mysql_pwd,
  database : process.env.mysql_db
});

exports.getConnection = function(callback) {
  mainDb.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
      callback(err, connection);
  });
};
```

and my register.js code looks like this...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require(__dirname, 'models/db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());


router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', { title: 'Register for a free account' });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  var today = new Date();
  var users = {
    "username": req.body.username,
    "email":req.body.email,
    "password":req.body.password,
    "created":today,
    "modified":today
  };
  db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ', users, function(err, result) {
    connection.release();
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    });
  });
  res.redirect('/index');
});
module.exports = router;
```

I don't know if my app.js is relevant for this question, but it looks like this...

```
const express = require('express');
      http = require('http');
      path = require('path');
      session = require('express-session');
      app = express();
      mysql      = require('mysql');
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');
      db = require(__dirname, 'models/db')

var index = require('./routes/index');
var register = require('./routes/register');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/', register);

var engine = require('ejs-mate');
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


var server = http.createServer(app);

var port = 8995;
server.listen(port);

module.exports = app;
```

When I start app.js I get no errors, only when I make my post request from my form, the error shows up in my browser. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

At db.js you are exporting only a function. But at register.js, you are trying to use `db` as if it was an object.

To solve your problem, at db.js, just export an object, instead of a function:

```
function getConnection(callback) {
   mainDb.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
   if (err) {
       console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
       return;
   }
   callback(err, connection);
}

module.exports = { getConnection };
```

Comment: Try this new version

Comment: Hey, so it worked, BUT, In my register.js I had to change db.getConnection to db.connect, but it doesn't hit that block :/ when I change it back to db.getConnection it still gives me the same error, weird

Comment: It worked for me (obviously a simpler version of it). In order to debug and hunt the error, I suggest you to print on console the actual `db` object as recieved from `db = require(__dirname, 'models/db');`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need use getConnection method only exports the pool, according the documentation.

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: sorry, but that's not much help. My connection details are in a separate folder and I'm trying to access it via the models folder

Comment: This should work even on separated folders. You need to export the _mainDb_ pool. The V8 engine doesn't reopen the connection after evaluated.

Maybe this implementation works.

```js
exports.db = mainDb
```

Comment: Hi @lukaswilkeer I have already fixed my issue, but thanks, that totally makes sense!